# Chip for power management

Tags: power-supply, power, low-power, battery-operated

I am working on a project which is powered by a 24VDC power supply. My plan is to replace the 24VDC power with a battery. To make the battery last long, I am planning to auto shutdown when microcontroller detects that it is idle for 2 minutes.

I can achieve this using a circuit described in [this article (webpage)](https://randomnerdtutorials.com/latching-power-switch-circuit-auto-power-off-circuit-esp32-esp8266-arduino). However, I need help to achieve a solution for the following functionality which is like a laptop's power supply management.

1. Microcontroller should be able to power off the circuit
2. One physical button is sufficient to signal the power-on and power-off.
3. The action of **short press** on button will connect the battery to the circuit if it is powered-off.
4. The action of **short press** on button will do nothing if the circuit is already powered-on.
5. The action of **long press** on button will disconnect the battery if the circuit is powered-on.
6. The action of **long press** on button will connect the battery if the circuit is powered-off.

Comment: "I want to know if there exists a dedicated chip" Sorry, request for recommendations of specific products are off-topic for this site.

Comment: @ElliotAlderson, I corrected that part of my question. Thank you for reminding me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**TL;DR**: This all sounds like you need a pushbutton, and a microcontroller. That's it. A low-power microcontroller is pretty much the application-specific IC for this.

Modern microcontroller deep sleep currents are very low – almost certainly lower than the self-discharge of your 24 V battery-based power source, so disconnecting the microcontroller simply makes little to no difference to battery life. So, you could simply use a linear voltage regulator with low quiescent current to go from 24 V to 3.3 V (or whatever the microcontroller uses, but 3.3 V is pretty universal in modern microcontrollers), and configure it to wake up on the change of the input pin you connect to your switch.

Alternatively, use the push button to supply power to the aforementioned linear regulator, and use the output of that to switch on a high-side MOSFET in parallel to said button.

The long-press turn-off logic is just a matter of observing the button with your microcontroller.

To stress this: *start by actually writing down your power budget*. What is your battery capacity? What is the sleep mode current of your microcontroller and the necessary voltage regulator? What is the battery self discharge? Resulting from these numbers, derive your battery lives under different approaches.

If your battery life is 1% longer if you actually disconnect vs just switching to sleep mode on paper, then this whole thing simply makes no sense.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fBJXsf.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Alternatively, a lot of switch-mode DC/DC converter ICs have an enable pin that replaces everything right of the ESP32.

Comment: There are two problems with this approach.
1. If the micro-controller hangs for some reason, it will drain the whole battery
2. I don't want the DC-DC converters to be switched-on while it is in the sleep mode.

Comment: 1. not a real problem. Microcontroller are quite reliable. and even if your software isn't, that's why microcontrollers have what is called "watchdog units." 2. you don't need such. For the sleep-mode current, you'll want a linear regulator, anyways.

Comment: I got it now. You are proposing to use a dedicated microcontroller for this purpose, right?

Comment: no, I'm not. Your current microcontroller should have the required functionality.

Comment: My current microcontroller is an ESP32. It uses more than 100mA. So, it is not a promising idea to use a Linear regulator. Especially when I must make a big step down from 24V to 3.3V.

Comment: It uses 100mA only when fully active with WiFi. In (deep) sleep mode or hibernation mode it uses less than 10μA. There are newer ESP32 models that use even less than that. The issue is that many boards that use the ESP32 have all kinds of unnecessary components such as LEDs and USB-to-Serial converters. Those should be removed or disabled.

Comment: so, yeah. The ESP32 definitely is feasible for all this. It has the required sleep, wake-up functionality, a low-power sleep mode. All you need to add is a low-quiescent current low-power linear voltage regulator, the button with a pull-up resistor against ground, and a high-side switch (MOSFET). That's it.

Comment: 100mA is a big current for the linear regulator, because it will generate a 2.07W power loss. It is a problem for overall efficiency and for power dissipation.

Comment: the 100 mA never flow through the linear regulator. Again, the linear regulator is only used to supply the sleep current. You'd use the same DC/DC converter you currently have as soon as the microcontroller wakes up and turns on the high-side switch.

Comment: @MarcusMüller, if possible, please include a circuit diagram of what you have described in the comment you posted before the last one.

Answer (score 3):

I usually do something like this, zero power consumption when it's off (except for MOS drain leakages). I don't know specific chip to do it.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f7YANj.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>